# Weak Derivative of a function given by an integral

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, weak-derivatives, integration-by-parts

Today I have the following question: Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^d$ be open. Say $g:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is a continuously differentiable function on $\mathbb R$, and $f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is weakly differentiable on $\Omega$. Let $a$ be a real number. Define $F:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb R$ by:
$$
F(x)=\int\limits_a^{f(x)}g(y)\,dy
$$

The question: $\textbf{Is $F$ a weakly differentiable function on $\Omega$?}$ Note that, if $f$ is continuously differentiable on $\Omega$, then so is $F$, and by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,
$$
\nabla F(x)=g(f(x))\nabla f(x).
$$
Due to the above we have the expectation that, if $F$ is weakly differentiable, then its weak derivative should be given by the above formula. But this is not clear to me in the general case here described. Any help?

Comment: Alright, after finding the extremely useful ACL characterization of Sobolev functions (see [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Absolutely_continuous_on_lines_.28ACL.29_characterization_of_Sobolev_functions)), the question becomes straightforward if one assumes that $f\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ for some $p\in[1,+\infty)$. Simply prove that on almost every line parallel to a coordinate axis, $F$ is absolutely continuous. To do this, use the fact that $g$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$ and that almost every restriction of $f$ to each line is absolutely continuous.